# Generate DateTime Stamp on Session Timeout c#

Tags: c#, session, datetime

I am trying to generate a datetime stamp when the session times out on my web site.... I know this might seem like a really basic and almost stupid question, but I can not figure it out for the life of me.

Ideally I would like to generate this in the code behind `c#`.

I have set the session timeout to one minute in the `web.config` file just for testing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a Global.asax and use the Session_End event handler in the code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wnat to write some code on session timeout, you can use Session_End event of Global.asax, write your logic with in this event.

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //your logic goes here
}
```

> The above code only works when using
>
> InProc Session Mode

If you are using Outproc session mode then this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21156/ASP-NET-HttpModule-for-handling-session-end-with-S) will help you out

Comment: if you are using outproc session mode, it will not fire, because Session_end only fires incase of the Inproc session mode.

Comment: is there an alternate solution for my case then?

Comment: Hope this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21156/ASP-NET-HttpModule-for-handling-session-end-with-S) will help you, if you are using outproc mode

Answer (score -1):

Look into the `DateTime` class. What you are looking for specifically is `DateTime.Now`

Comment: I understand how to get a stamp, it is generating it on session timeout that I do not know

Comment: Okay, well you can be a little more specific next time